# Copy Datatable to Database asp VB

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, sqlbulkcopy

i want to copy datatable to database
this is my code

```
Public Sub PerformBulkCopy(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal tablename As String)
    Using sqlcon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(PyrDLL.KoneksiLokal(Session("IP")).ConnectionString)
        sqlcon.Open()
        Using s As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(sqlcon)
            s.DestinationTableName = "" & tablename & ""
            s.WriteToServer(dt)
            s.Close()
        End Using
        sqlcon.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

its clear, but when it have some error in one row its make not copy at all, i want its copy row where no have error
anyone can help me?

Comment: That's how bulk copy works. It's your responsibility to validate the data BEFORE you use bulk copy. If you can't do that then don't use bulk copy.

Comment: The bulk insert will stop if any error occurred in-process. You need to validate `DataTable` contents by using extension methods and create valid `DataTable` with `CopyToDataTable` method. What is your `DataTable` content looks like?